# Confused over "getting and clearing" when working in Microsoft C

Tags: c, functional-programming

I am confused over *"getting and clearing"* when working in Microsoft C. Like when or how you get the current status of word settings, and what function to use?

Comment: Are you confused about how it works in Microsoft C as opposed to, say, GNU C?  Or are you confused about how it works in C in general (but you happen to be using Microsoft's C compiler)?  C is not a functional programming language; what relevance does the functional programming tag have to the question?  Which language(s) are you comparing C with?

Comment: More details please. What "word settings"? Also, what does C have to do with functional programming? FP does not mean "programming using functions" - it's a rather different language design philosophy, which C does not follow. Don't add a comment here, edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Research the following;  Match Functions, Floating-point-math-package. and exception handling. This will greatly help you understand  the "get and clear functions.

Here is an example of the Getting and Clearing function:

To get the current status word setting, use the `_status87()` function as follows:

```
unsigned sw_setting;
sw_setting = _status87():
```

To clear (0x0000) the status word setting before a suspicious floating point operation is performed, use the `_clear87()` function as follows:

```
unsigned sw-setting;
old_sw_setting = _clear87();
```

The status word is also cleared (0x0000) whenever the function `_fpreset()` is called to initialize the floating point math package.

Comment: HOW'D YOU GUESS WHAT WAS THAT ABOUT???

Comment: If this is actually what the OP was asking about, you should get a 'Clairvoyant' badge. :)